# How to use Swift REST API with Bluemix Object Store?

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

I want to write a Java program running externally to Bluemix that interacts with the instance of the Bluemix Object Store I have provisioned.

The program will use the Swift REST APIs to interact with the service.

The documentation for how to use the REST API is mainly missing in the service documentation and the OpenStack documentation is not helpful with specifics on how to reach the Bluemix service.

Can someone tell me what headers to set and what URL to use to authenticate with the service, and then what headers to set and what URL to use to further interact with the service ?  Where do I find this information for my instance of the service ?  It doesn't seem to all be available in the service credentials that are displayed.

Also, do I need to do basic authentication every time a REST call is made, or is there a way to get a token ?  Where is that explained ?

Answer (score 0):

The Bluemix Object Storage uses the OpenStack Identity (Keystone) v3 API for authentication.  For complete documentation on the REST API, see: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-identity-v3.html

Since your application will be developed in Java, I'd suggest you use the openstack4j SDK.  For example of using openstack4j with Bluemix object storage service, see: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connecting-to-ibm-object-storage-for-bluemix-with-java/